# Rendering the React component inside the same react component

Tags: reactjs

I am wondering how rendering the same component inside the component behave.
Want to create a nested tree and this works with no issues but just wondering if this is a good practise and if there is any better way to do handle this and perplexed how this works.

Thanks

```
const obj = { name: "GranParent", children :[ {name: "Parent1", children :[{ name :"child" , children:[]}] }, {name: "Parent2", children :[{ name :"child"}] }] };

const DisParent = () => <DisplayChildren elem={{...obj}} />

 const DisplayChildren = (props) => {
  const propName = props.elem;
  const nameProperty = "name";

  return (
    <ul>
      {propName.map((instance, idx) => {
        return (
          <li key={idx}>
            <a href={"#" + instance.url}>{instance[nameProperty]}</a>
            {instance.children && (
             // see I am calling the component itself
              <DisplayChildren elem={instance.children}> </DisplayChildren>
            )}
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, looks fine to me! Here are couple of things I will consider to apply for readability and semantic:

First, I'll separate the `obj`:

ListComponent.js

```
const obj = {
  name: "GranParent",
  children: [
    {
      name: "Parent1",
      children: [
       {
         name: "child",
         children: []
       }
      ]
    },
   {
     name: "Parent2",
     children: [
      {
        name: "child"
      }
     ]
   }
 ]
}

export default obj
```

Now, import `obj` and use it.

Second, I would wrap children elements in `ul` since it's inside `li`:

```
<ul key={`some-unique-key`}>
  <DisplayChildren elem={instance.children}> </DisplayChildren>
</ul>
```

If you're still considering if it is good or bad, then check [this blog](https://medium.com/@swatisucharita94/recursive-rendering-in-react-42666102eae2), you may find how it is okay to use recursive rendering.

---

If you ask me with personal experience, then I would not render recursive component. Coz, it looks more difficult when more details appears to come (more children, its props, etc). It will be more difficult to handle each component states, etc. If you go into a problem, then you might not be able to find easily. More headaches may appear. React suggest us that tiny component as far as possible we should considering that is called code splitting. Just google about `code splitting` in react if you don't know.

I would never ever try recursive rendering in my project while it can be done very smoothly with splitting:

```
const Parent = () => { }

<Parent {...} />
<Parent ... />
```

Or map them and render `<Parent />`.

Comment: Thanks,  I understand the readability sematics I just posted that as an example. How do I achieve the same with code splitting and go deepdown the nested children? I tried different things but only this seems to have good readability and simple.